# Создание webp в VITE

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, gulp, vite

Пытаюсь настроить в VITE, чтобы имеющийся формат изображений конвертировался в формат webp, но не заменяя оригиналы, а дополнительно складывались в dist, чтобы потом подставлять в браузере, в зависимости от наличия поддержки формата.

Единственный пример в доках - conversion, она преобразует, но заменяет собой, других методов в доках к unplugin-imagemin. я не нашёл, буду благодарен за помощь

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import imagemin from 'unplugin-imagemin/vite';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
      imagemin({
        conversion: [
          {from: 'png', to: 'webp'},
        ],
      })
    ]
  }
)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)